# mongo db which is runing on ec2 instance , during connection with node app it is saying you can not use ipv4

Tags: node.js, aws-ec2-instance-connect

when my node app trying to connect mongo db url which is runing on ec2 instance , it is saying you can not use ipv4 , i use dns name of mongo , again same issue coming

UNHANDLED REJECTION!  Shutting down...
Error querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.ec2-52-66-138-70.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: Could you provide the code that is causing that error?